# In oracle., what is the syntax to replace or refer to special characters in reg_exp, like a $ or @ or & or |

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM employees 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (first_name, '$')
```

`REGEXP_LIKE`  is not looking for `$` sign, its looking for end of the line. can you please help on exactly looking for `$` sign.

Comment: With something as simple as this you don't need regex: `INSTR()` or plain ol` `LIKE()` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

[Escape the special character with a `\` character.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm#1006826)

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (first_name, '\$')
```

Or else wrap it in square brackets `[]`.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (first_name, '[$]')
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c8eb/2)